# Symlinks are inaccessible by their full path on OS X

Tags: macos, shell, path, symbolic-link

I have symlinks pointing to applications placed in /usr/local/bin which is in the path. However, I can't run these applications from other folders.

Even more weird, I can't access them by the full path to the symlink.

```
[mqudsi@iqudsi:Desktop/EasyBCD]$ echo $path                       (03-26 13:42)
/opt/local/bin /opt/local/sbin /usr/local/bin /usr/local/sbin/ /usr/local/CrossPack-AVR/bin /usr/bin /bin /usr/sbin /sbin /usr/local/bin /usr/X11/bin

[mqudsi@iqudsi:local/bin]$ ls -l /usr/local/bin                   (03-26 13:47)
total 24280
-rwxr-xr-x  1 mqudsi  wheel    18464 May 14  2009 ascii-xfr
-rwxr-xr-x  1 mqudsi  wheel    12567 Mar 25 04:50 brew
-rwxr-xr-x  1 mqudsi  wheel    17768 Dec 11 12:41 bsdiff
-rwxr-xr-x  1 mqudsi  wheel    43024 Mar 28  2009 dumpsexp
-rwxr-xr-x  1 mqudsi  wheel      280 Sep 10  2009 easy_install
-rwxr-xr-x  1 mqudsi  wheel      288 Sep 10  2009 easy_install-2.6
-rwxr-xr-x  1 mqudsi  wheel    39696 Apr  5  2009 fuse_wait
lrwxr-xr-x  1 mqudsi  wheel       29 Mar 25 04:53 git -> ../Cellar/git/1.7.0.3/bin/git

[mqudsi@iqudsi:local/bin]$ /usr/local/bin/git                     (03-26 13:47)
zsh: no such file or directory: /usr/local/bin/git
```

Clearly the link *is* there, but I'm not able to get it to it :S

Comment: Can you run any of the other, non-linked, apps in /usr/local/bin, either via 'path' or by specifying their full path, or are only symlinked apps affected?  What about in the parent, grandparent, ..., directories?

Comment: The symlink exists, but does /usr/local/Cellar/git/1.7.0.3/...whatever exist?  What is the output of `file /usr/local/bin/git`?

Comment: coneslayer, with the `file` command I realized the symlink was broken. I had expected that using a broken symlink would display an error if that had been the case, but I guess not. Can you please post your comment as an answer below so that I can accept it? Thanks for setting me on the right track.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Reposted from comment at OP's request]

The symlink exists, but does `/usr/local/Cellar/git/1.7.0.3/...` whatever exist? What is the output of `file /usr/local/bin/git`?

Comment: BTW, one reason that I phrased these as diagnostic questions is that if the thing you're trying to run is a script that starts with "#!", you can get the same error message due to the interpreter on the "#!" line not existing.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed your symlink is a relative path.  That should be an absolute.

Comment: Relative links should work, and have the advantage that they will continue to work if that part of the directory tree is moved somewhere else.